# How to access `match.params` outside of router?

Tags: react-router-v4

I'm trying to get `match.params` for a container of my app.

I tried using `withRouter(AppContainer)` and `match.params` would always be empty.

```js
// Routes
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Router } from 'react-router';
import { createBrowserHistory} from 'history';
import AppContainer from './app-container';
...
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
  <AppContainer>
    <Switch>
      ...
      <Route exact path="/:path1/:path2" component={() => <div>hello</div>} />
      ...
    </Switch>
  </AppContainer>
</Router>

// app-container.js
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
const AppContainer = (props) => {
  const { match } = props;
  console.log(match.params); // This will always be empty
  return <div>whatever</div>;
};
export default withRouter(AppContainer);
```

Navigate to `/foo/bar`.
I expect `match.params` in `AppContainer` to be `{ path1: 'foo', path2: 'bar'}`, but they are always `{}`.

I think it's because `AppContainer` is outside the routes that have route params that I'm interested in.

So, I'm wondering whether there's another way that I could do here so that I could get the route params inside `AppContainer`. Ideally without using a redux store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, there's no way to use `match`.

It seems to me the only way to do so is by using `matchPath`.

```
import { matchPath, withRouter } from 'react-router';

const Test = ({ location }) => {
  /*
  `matchPath` will return `null` if it doesn't match the path format.
  If it matches, it will return some object with parameters put into it
  nicely like `match.params`.
  */
  matchPath(location.search, { path: '/:path1/:path2' });
};
export default withRouter(Test);
```

Answer (score 4):

If someone is looking for how to solve this with hooks, you can simply use the useRouteMatch() hook. It is even a little cleaner.

```
import {useRouteMatch} from 'react-router-dom';

const Test = () => {

const { params } = useRouteMatch('/:path1/:path2');

}
```

Comment: For those using v6: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#replace-useroutematch-with-usematch